# How to generate OpenAPI3.x schema "examples:" section using Swashbuckle & ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swashbuckle

I'm using the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters.SwaggerResponseExampleAttribute` attribute to generate Swagger documentation that includes a single response example for a given HTTP status code, for a (.NET 6) ASP.NET Web API controller method, like so:

```
[SwaggerOperation(summary: "Delete all items in a cart.", description: "<p>BLAH BLAH BLAH.</p>")]
[SwaggerResponse(statusCode: 200, description: "<p>The API request was successfully processed; an object describing the empty shopping cart is returned.</p>", type: typeof(GetCartSummaryResponse)), SwaggerResponseExample(statusCode: 200, examplesProviderType: typeof(CartApi_DeleteAllItemsInCart_Http200ResponseExampleProvider))]
[SwaggerResponse(statusCode: 422, description: "The API request was unsuccessfully processed; one or more business requirements failed to be met as the request was processed.", type: typeof(ProblemDetails))]
[SwaggerResponseExample(statusCode: 422, examplesProviderType: typeof(CartApi_DeleteAllItemsInCart_Http422ResponseExampleProvider))]
[HttpPost("/cart/clear")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public ActionResult<GetCartSummaryResponse> DeleteAllItemsInCart() 
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Now I'd like to provide *multiple* examples of HTTP 422 response bodies that might be returned in the API response body, under specific conditions.

I'd planned on using my endpoint's `examples:` section in the OpenAPI 3.x document to accomplish this, like so:

```
paths:
  '/cart/clear':
    post:
      tags:
        - CartApi
      summary: Delete all items in a cart.
      description: <p><i>BLAH BLAH BLAH.</i></p>
      operationId: CartApi_DeleteAllItemsInCart
      responses:
        '200':
          description: <p>The API request was successfully processed; an object describing the empty shopping cart is returned.</p>
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/GetCartSummaryResponse'
              example:
                cartGuid: 0fa1ef5f-5395-4679-901d-fd6c941f3460
                cartItems: []
        '422':
          description: The API request was unsuccessfully processed; some other problem happened.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ProblemDetails'
              examples:
                Shopping cart ID is null or whitespace:
                  value:
                    type: 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422'
                    title: Shopping cart was not found.
                    status: 422
                    detail: Shopping cart ID is null, empty, blank, or whitespace.
                Shopping cart ID not found:
                  value:
                    type: 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422'
                    title: Shopping cart was not found.
                    status: 422
                    detail: Shopping cart ID was not found.
                    cartGuid: 0fa1ef5f-5395-4679-901d-fd6c941f3460
```

I've fairly certain the OpenAPI 3.x spec supports this feature -- see the "*Multiple examples in response bodies:*" section on the "[*Adding Examples*](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/)" page. However, I can't figure out if Swashbuckle supports rendering the `examples:` section in an OpenAPI 3.x document yet.  And if it *does* already support it, I've had no luck figuring out what attributes to use / what the code to do this looks like.

Any help would be greatly appreciated -- thanks in advance!

Comment: did you checked this [article](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/multiple-request-response-examples-for-swagger-ui-in-asp-net-core-864c0bdc6619). it shows how to generate multiple example

Comment: I hadn't come across that article, & had never seen/heard of the `IMultipleExamplesProvider<T>` interface.  I'm currently using the `IExampleProvider<T>` interface... will give this a shot right now.  Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@CodingMytra` commented on my OP & pointed me at [an article](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/multiple-request-response-examples-for-swagger-ui-in-asp-net-core-864c0bdc6619) that mentions how to use the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters` package's `IMultipleExamplesProvider<T>` interface to generate the OpenAPI `examples:` section for a given API endpoint & HTTP response code.

For the sake of completeness, here's my class that implements `IMultipleExamplesProvider<T>`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters;

namespace api.Models.Responses.Examples._4xx;

public class CartApi_DeleteAllItemsInCart_Http422ResponseExamplesProvider : IMultipleExamplesProvider<ProblemDetails>
{
    public IEnumerable<SwaggerExample<ProblemDetails>> GetExamples()
    {
        yield return SwaggerExample.Create(
            name: "Shopping cart ID is invalid.", 
            value: new ProblemDetails {
                Type = $@"https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422",
                Status = 422,
                Title = "Shopping cart ID is invalid.",
                Detail = "Shopping cart ID is null, empty, or whitespace, & cannot be used to access a shopping cart.",
                Extensions = {{ "cartGuid", "BLAH_BLAH_BLAH" }}
            }
        );
        
        yield return SwaggerExample.Create(
            name: "Unable to access shopping cart.", 
            value: new ProblemDetails {
                Type = $@"https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422",
                Status = 422,
                Title = "Unable to access shopping cart.",
                Detail = "Shopping cart ID is valid, but could not be used to access the shopping cart."
            }
        );
    }
}
```

After that, I used the new pluralized `CartApi_DeleteAllItemsInCart_Http422ResponseExamplesProvider` class in my `[SwaggerResponseExample]` attribute & it generated the OpenAPI 3.x `examples:` section the way I'd expected:

```
'422':
  description: The API request was unsuccessfully processed; shopping cart ID was not found.
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/ProblemDetails'
      examples:
        Shopping cart ID is invalid.:
          value:
            type: 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422'
            title: Shopping cart ID is invalid.
            status: 422
            detail: 'Shopping cart ID is null, empty, or whitespace, & cannot be used to access a shopping cart.'
            cartGuid: 0fa1ef5f-5395-4679-901d-fd6c941f3460
        Unable to access shopping cart.:
          value:
            type: 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422'
            title: Unable to access shopping cart.
            status: 422
            detail: 'Shopping cart ID is valid, but could not be used to access the shopping cart.'
```